# Python time format for rolling mean

Tags: python, pandas, format

I want to calculate the rolling average of a column (call it c1) over the past 15 mins. c1 has data type of decimal number. I imported np and pd. And what I did is use `c2 = c1.rolling('900s').mean()` because 15min * 60s/min = 900s and this works. But still I want to know the time format for minute. Can someone help me with this? Also, it will be the best if someone can provide me with other time formate, such as year, month, quarter, day, hour. Thx.

Comment: There must be some typos here. 15*60 = 900? Also, what is the data type of the column? Are you using numpy? pandas? Should rollig be rolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I understand you correctly:

First I build a dataframe indexed by times that run for fifteen minutes with a data column of Gaussian noise.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> times = [pd.Timestamp(1996,5,6,11,m) for m in range(1,16)]
>>> import random
>>> v = [random.gauss(0,1) for m in range(1,16)]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'V': v}, index=times)
```

Then I duplicate your result.

```
>>> df.rolling('900s').mean()
                            V
1996-05-06 11:01:00 -1.263849
1996-05-06 11:02:00 -0.806934
1996-05-06 11:03:00  0.344626
1996-05-06 11:04:00  0.497085
1996-05-06 11:05:00  0.549562
1996-05-06 11:06:00  0.554746
1996-05-06 11:07:00  0.630223
1996-05-06 11:08:00  0.650979
1996-05-06 11:09:00  0.575184
1996-05-06 11:10:00  0.576052
1996-05-06 11:11:00  0.438371
1996-05-06 11:12:00  0.577996
1996-05-06 11:13:00  0.392422
1996-05-06 11:14:00  0.292866
1996-05-06 11:15:00  0.211225
```

Now I can also get 5-minute means. To do this I used the documentation available at [Offset Aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

```
>>> df.rolling('5min').mean()
                            V
1996-05-06 11:01:00 -1.263849
1996-05-06 11:02:00 -0.806934
1996-05-06 11:03:00  0.344626
1996-05-06 11:04:00  0.497085
1996-05-06 11:05:00  0.549562
1996-05-06 11:06:00  0.918466
1996-05-06 11:07:00  1.205086
1996-05-06 11:08:00  0.834790
1996-05-06 11:09:00  0.637663
1996-05-06 11:10:00  0.602542
1996-05-06 11:11:00  0.298720
1996-05-06 11:12:00  0.504877
1996-05-06 11:13:00 -0.021270
1996-05-06 11:14:00 -0.215305
1996-05-06 11:15:00 -0.518430
```